# fragments visibility gone and visible on respective button click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have view pager and bottom navigation bar with five fragments, tried to hide other fragments when first fragment is called.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

protected void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
    item.setChecked(true);


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_home:
            displayFragment(DefaultFragment.class);
            ft.hide(FavouriteFragment.class);//need help here
            break;
        case R.id.action_info:
            displayFragment(FavouriteFragment.class);
            break;
        case R.id.action_msg:
            displayFragment(NotifyFragment.class);
            break;
        case R.id.action_profile:
            displayFragment(ProfileFragment.class);
            break;
        case R.id.action_history:
            displayFragment(OrderHistoryFragment.class);
            break;

    }
}
```

[image]

background you can see the previous fragments are coming, though the clicked fragment have background color blue

Comment: I am confused now how to do it..need help

Comment: On Selection ????

Comment: What do you mean tried to hide the other fragments ? If you are using bottom bar, at a time, there will only be one fragment visible at a time.

Comment: You don't need to hide any fragment, add all fragment to viewpager adapter and setup viewpager with bottom nav view, so whenever you click any menu item of bottom menu, viewpager item will display accordingly.

Comment: refer this link https://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/

Comment: @TakeInfos it is overlaping all the fragment

Comment: @Preety What you want to do exactly and why are you hiding fragment?

Comment: @Preety  seems like you haven't use viewpager adapter right?

Comment: @Ezio you said correct ,but question is the all fragments have recycler view,and while clicking the previous fragments arise also and gets overlapped

Comment: @Preety can you add the whole file's code?

Comment: @TakeInfos  how can add  screenshot here

Comment: You have option to attach the image file. on top bar panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_home:
            Fragment fragment = new DefaultFragment();
            loadFragment(fragment);
            break;
        case R.id.action_info:
            Fragment fragment = new FavouriteFragment();
            loadFragment(fragment);
            break;
        case R.id.action_msg:
            Fragment fragment = new NotifyFragment();
            loadFragment(fragment);
            break;
        case R.id.action_profile:
            Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            loadFragment(fragment);
            break;
        case R.id.action_history:
            Fragment fragment = new OrderHistoryFragment();
            loadFragment(fragment);
            break;

    }

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_login_activity, fragment);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, 
    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

Comment: You can define and initialize FragmentTransaction and FragmentManager above as you are doing before and use ft and fm in method instead of initializing everytime on method call. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Let me try this